# ELK: Setup multiple http inputs of logstash ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

**Question:**

- How to setup multiple http inputs of logstash ELK stack

**What I already have:**

- Working **ELK docker image** based on: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk
- Working **logstash-input-http-plugin** based on: https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin
- My logstash.conf file looks like:

> ```
> input {
>   http {
>         host => "0.0.0.0"
>         port => "5000"
>     }
> }
>
> output {
>   elasticsearch {
>       hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
>   }
> }
> ```

- And I can easly send my Component logs (as JSON) using postman on URL: http://localhost:5000

**What I need:**

- Multiple http inputs because I have multiple Components - something like (but second input does not listen to requests):

> ```
> input {
>   http {
>         host => "0.0.0.0"
>         port => "5000"
>   }
>   http {
>       host => "0.0.0.0"
>       port => "7070"
>   }
> }
> ```

- I have to distinguish those Components in Kibona

Comment: You can use the `type` settings in each of your `http` inputs to distinguish where the documents came from

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set a type for each input and use that type to generate the index name:

```
input {
  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => "5000"
    type => "A"
  }

  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => "5001"
    type => "B"
  }
}
```

Using the type may suffice, as you can filter the records using it. But you may also need to store each type of record in a different index since each type may use a different type for the same field. This causes a mapping conflict.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    index => "%{[type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not allowed to set up two endpoints of the same host and port. Moreover it is not allowed to set up on two different ports. First input always work fine but second input does not listen to any requests.

Comment: Sorry that's a TYPO.

Answer (score 3):

I already **resolve** this.

I needed **add a port** in my **docker-compose.yml** file in **logstash:** section like:

> ```
> ports:
>   - "5000:5000"
>   - "7070:7070"
> ```

And also

> ```
> type => "A"
> ```

Works nice.